# Streaming FM station audio

Tags: audio, audio-streaming

Is there any useful guides/tutorials on how to stream live FM station feed to a station's website ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use SHOUTcast dsp to capture sound coming from a soundcard and streaming it to a SHOUTcast server.

http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools

Go in the [winamp forums](http://forums.winamp.com/) to get more help on the subject